# How can I completely remove MySQL 8 from Redhat Linux so I can install MySQL 5?

Tags: mysql, redhat, yum

I am trying to install MySQL 5 on a machine where there was a previous (unsuccessful) attempt to install MySQL 8.

I installed the repo for MySQL 5:

```
yum localinstall https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql57-community-release-el7-9.noarch.rpm
```

I then ran:

```
yum install mysql-community-server
```

I get:

```
Error: Package: mysql-community-server-5.7.28-1.el7.x86_64 (mysql57-community)
           Requires: mysql-community-common(x86-64) = 5.7.28-1.el7
           Installed: mysql-community-common-8.0.18-1.el7.x86_64 (@mysql80-community)
               mysql-community-common(x86-64) = 8.0.18-1.el7
```

How to fix this?

If I run...

```
yum remove mysql mysql-server
```

I get...

```
No Match for argument: mysql
No Match for argument: mysql-server
No Packages marked for removal
```

Comment: Solved:  I needed to also do... yum remove mysql-community-common-8.0.18-1.el7.x86_64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to remove the old repo, like so...

```
yum remove mysql-community-common-8.0.18-1.el7.x86_64
```